# What's the default value of the Hibernate property hibernate.jdbc.factory_class?

Tags: hibernate, default-value

I want to provide a custom Batcher for Hibernate to use (for this reason: [hibernate insert batch with partitioned postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83093/hibernate-insert-batch-with-postgresql)), but I want to create a modification of whatever it's already using (BatchingBatcher or NonBatchingBatcher).  What's the default value of hibernate.jdbc.factory_class, or how can I figure out which Batcher Hibernate is currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the method createBatcherFactory in [this file](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory.java.html).

By default, the NonBatchingBatcher is used if the batch size is 0; otherwise the BatchingBatcher is used.

The default batch size is positive, so if the batch size is not set the BatchingBatcher will be used.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't be trusting line numbers anyway - that link might point to some other version in the future.